# Uploading Image From Angular to Laravel

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular4-forms

I have tried to upload an image from my Angular app to Laravel. My problem is that it can't be done. Is there something wrong with my code? I have to submit it using other input fields too. Please check my codes below.

> HTML

```
 <form [formGroup]="servicesForm" (ngSubmit)="onCreateService(servicesForm)">
    <div class="col-sm-8"> 
        <input  type="file" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" (change)="onSelectImage($event)" class="form-control" formControlName="icon">
    </div> 
     <button type="submit" >Save</button>
</form>
```

> TS

```
  onSelectImage(event) {
     this.selectedImage = new FormData();
     this.selectedImage.append('avatar', event.srcElement.files[0], event.srcElement.files[0].name);
     console.log(this.selectedImage);
  }

  onCreateService(form: FormGroup) {
    const formData = {
      image: this.selectedImage,
      name: this.servicesForm.get('name').value,
      amount: this.servicesForm.get('price').value,
      description: this.servicesForm.get('content').value
    };
    console.log(formData);
  }
```

[image]

Comment: What is the issue you are getting?

Comment: @Javascript Lover - SKT. The server says image: ["The image must be a file of type: jpg, jpeg]

Comment: I've posted one answer, please check once. You need to send entire data as formdata not only the image

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your `ts` code like below, you need to send entire data as `formdata` not only the image

```
  onSelectImage(event) {
     this.selectedImage = event.srcElement.files[0];
  }

  onCreateService(form: FormGroup) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', this.selectedImage, this.selectedImage.name);
    formData.append('name', this.servicesForm.get('name').value);
    formData.append('amount', this.servicesForm.get('price').value);
    formData.append('description', this.servicesForm.get('content').value);
    console.log(formData);
  }
```

Comment: The error is not now the image. The errors are  amount: ["The amount field is required."]
description: ["The description field is required."]
name: ["The name field is required."]

Comment: @Joseph How you are accessing files at server side? using `$_FILES` array?

Comment: Yes. I access it like that

Comment: @Joseph then instead of `formdata` in ts file, you can set headers as `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` for this request and you've to send `C:\fakepath\xyz.jpeg`

Comment: @Joseph I can help you after 45 mins, I am going office. Meanwhile if you got best answers that's fine.

Comment: Yes. i've send this before C:\fakepath\xyz.jpeg . and its not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179724/discussion-between-javascript-lover-skt-and-joseph).

Comment: Did you set the headers as `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`

Comment: Hello did you get it?

Comment: @Joseph still you are facing the issue?

Comment: I am on the discussion room, you can join https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179724/discussion-between-javascript-lover-skt-and-joseph

Answer (score 0):

You try using this coding. This image Uploding code is using Frond-end Angular  to  back-end Laravel-8.

Below is the Angular ts file coding. **saveOrUpdate** which contains file save coding  and coding for updating

```
import { Component,  OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms';
import { Product } from '../../models/product.model';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-add-product',
    templateUrl: './add-product.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./add-product.component.css']
})
export class AddProductComponent implements OnInit {

    file: any;
    imagePath: any;
    currentSupplierId: number;

    constructor(
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private http: HttpClient,
        ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.imagePath = environment.baseUrl + "/public/img/products/";
    }

    onFileChanged(event) {
        console.log(event);
        this.file = event.target.files[0];

        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = e => {
            return this.imageSrc = reader.result;
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(this.file);
    }

    saveOrUpdate(product: Product) {
                    debugger;
                    const myFormData = new FormData();
                    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
                    headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
                    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
                    myFormData.append('image', this.file);
                    myFormData.append('code', product.code);
                    this.http.post(environment.utilityApiBasePath + 'upload', myFormData, {
                        headers: headers
                    }).subscribe(data => {
                        console.log(data);
                    });
                   
                } else {
                    const myFormData = new FormData();
                    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
                    headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
                    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
                    myFormData.append('image', this.file);
                    myFormData.append('code', product.code);
                    this.http.delete(environment.utilityApiBasePath + 'deleteImage/' + product.code + '.jpg').subscribe(
                        data1 => {
                            console.log(data1);
                            this.http.post(environment.utilityApiBasePath + 'upload', myFormData, {
                                headers: headers
                            }).subscribe(data => {
                                console.log(data);
                            });
                        });
    }
```

This is the Larwell controller file coding.

```
$file->move(public_path('supplier'), $picture);
```

We need to create the path parallel in the coding above **supplier** . in this path should be we create in the public folder in the Larwell file.

```
  public function uploadProfilePhoto(Request $request) {
        if ($request->hasFile('image'))
        {
            $file      = $request->file('image');
            $filename  = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            // $picture   = date('His').'-'.$filename;
            $picture =  $request['code'].'.jpg';
            $file->move(public_path('/supplier'), $picture);
            return response()->json(["message" => "Image Uploaded Succesfully"]);
        }
        else
        {
            return response()->json(["message" => "Select image first."]);
        }

    }
```

This will delete the old image in the folder when I update and just re-cash the new image. So below is the image to delete code

```
  public function deleteImage($image){
        $filename = public_path().'/supplier/'.$image;
        \File::delete($filename);
        return response()->json(['message'=> 'Successfully Deleted' ]);
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

**index.html**

```
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div class="file-upload">
    <input type="text" ng-model="name">
    <input type="file" file-model="myFile"/>
    <button ng-click="uploadFile()">upload me</button>
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
        var modelSetter = model.assign;

        element.bind('change', function(){
            scope.$apply(function(){
                modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
            });
        });
    }
   };
}]);

// We can write our own fileUpload service to reuse it in the controller
myApp.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl, name){
         var fd = new FormData();
         fd.append('file', file);
         fd.append('name', name);
         $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
             transformRequest: angular.identity,
             headers: {'Content-Type': undefined,'Process-Data': false}
         })
         .success(function(){
            console.log("Success");
         })
         .error(function(){
            console.log("Success");
         });
     }
 }]);

 myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', function($scope, fileUpload){

   $scope.uploadFile = function(){
        var file = $scope.myFile;
        console.log('file is ' );
        console.dir(file);

        var uploadUrl = "save_form.php";
        var text = $scope.name;
        fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl, text);
   };

}]);
```

**save_form.php**

```
<?php

     $target_dir = "./upload/";
     $name = $_POST['name'];
     print_r($_FILES);
     $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

     move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);

     //write code for saving to database 
     include_once "config.php";

     // Create connection
     $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
     // Check connection
     if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
     }

     $sql = "INSERT INTO MyData (name,filename) VALUES ('".$name."','".basename($_FILES["file"]["name"])."')";

     if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
         echo json_encode($_FILES["file"]); // new file uploaded
     } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
     }

     $conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: Im not using AngularJS